# Why are the following functions not equivalent

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to find 
$$\lim_{x\to-\infty}\sqrt{x^2 + 2x} - \sqrt{x^2 - 2x}.$$

However, I kept getting $2$ instead of $-2$, so I graphed the function to see what was going on. See the  picture below.

http://puu.sh/k7Y3f/684aeed22b.png

I found the issue in the steps I took, and it boiled down this. To summarize my steps, I rationalized the function, and then factored out $\sqrt{x^2}$ from each term in the denominator (green graph). However as soon as I sqrt those $x^2$'s, I get a different function? What gives? Why is the purple graph different from the green one?

Comment: Have you remembered that $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$? (In particular, for $x < 0$, $\sqrt{x^2}=-x$.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not like negative numbers, well, just apply a change of variable bringing them into positive numbers:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \lim_{x\to -\infty}\left(\sqrt{x^2+2x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x}\right)&=&\lim_{z\to +\infty}\left(\sqrt{z^2-2z}-\sqrt{z^2+2z}\right)\\&=&\lim_{z\to +\infty}\frac{-4z}{\sqrt{z^2+2z}+\sqrt{z^2-2z}}=\color{red}{-2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Comment: Precisely what I would do, I don't like negative numbers, they are so *negative*.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\sqrt{x^2+2x}-\sqrt{x^2-2x}
&=\frac{4x}{\sqrt{x^2+2x}+\sqrt{x^2-2x}}\\
&=\frac{4\mathrm{sgn}(x)}{\sqrt{1+\frac2x}+\sqrt{1-\frac2x}}\\
\end{align}
$$
Note that $\frac x{|x|}=\mathrm{sgn}(x)$.